# How to remove top and bottom lines from a file using sed, awk, etc. in 1 step

Tags: command-line, unix

I want to chop the top 13 and the last 6 lines from a file

There are several answers on unix/linux but they aren't working for me as the sed options used aren't available on osx, tac isn't available, etc.
Si I am posting here for a q&a that is specific to osx

Right now I am using

```
$ cat myfile | tail -n+14 | sed '$d' | sed '$d' | sed '$d' | sed '$d' | sed '$d' | sed '$d'
```

but am looking for a shorter '1 step at the end' way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all with `tail`

```
tail -n+14 FILE | tail -r | tail -n+7 | tail -r
```

- The first `tail` removes the top 13 lines
- The second `tail` reverses the line order
- The third `tail` removes the top 6 lines of the reversed order
- The last `tail` reverses the line order again

or with awk (with inspiration from patrix)

```
awk -v n="$(wc -l FILE)" 'NR > 13 && NR < (n-6+1)' FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
sed '1,13d' filename | head -n -6
```

The `sed` command can be used to delete a range of lines. Here 1 and 13 are min and max line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it:

```
sed -e '1,13d' -e $(($(wc -l <FILE)-6+1)),\$d FILE
```

Still needs two full passes over the input file though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try, not so elegant but works:

```
cat myFile | tail -n+14 | head -n $[ $(wc -l myFile | awk '{ print $1 }') - 19 ]
```

Note: last `19` is `13` + `6`

It's better to embed this into a script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                        

FILE="$1"
HEAD_STRIP="$2"
TAIL_STRIP="$3"

cat $FILE | tail -n+$[$HEAD_STRIP + 1] | head -n $[ $(wc -l $FILE | awk '{ print $1 }') - $[HEAD_STRIP + TAIL_STRIP] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work with OSX's version of `tail`:

```
cat file.txt | tail -n +7 | tail -r | tail -n +14 | tail -r
```

If you have gnu version of `head` (installed by: `brew install coreutils`) you can do:

```
cat file.txt | tail -n +7 | head -n -13
```

Comment: Besides the uuoc in both commands, you have the requirements backwards.